# Communication between HDFS clusters

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

After struggling through installations, I have few newbie questions. Lets say that I have 3 (lets name them A,B,C) different installations of Hadoop, and i just formatted B and C.

1. Is it possible to copy the data from A to B and C? If so how can I
   do that?
2. If I have PIG on A, would pig be able to load files from hdfs://B
   or hdfs://C?

I have tried the following:

1. Explicitly used `hadoop distcp hdfs:A
   hdfs:B`, which does not work due to this error :

   ```
    Invalid arguments: Call From Z77H2-A3/127.0.1.1 to local.research.com:8020
    failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection
    refused; For more details see: 
    http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
   ```
2. Same result on PIG:

   ```
   main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt -
   ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. Call From
   local.research.com/127.0.0.1 to 192.168.1.48:9000 failed on connection
   exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; 
   For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
   ```

Comment: Are all your clusters on the same Hadoop version?

Comment: same hadoop version, its currently on its latest 2.7.1